# Jquery filter out nested lists

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to select all the li elements in a list using Jquery, but not the li's in nested ul's inside some of those. In other words, only first-level list items.

```
<ul>
  <li>This one</li>
  <li>This one</li>
  <li>This one
   <ul>
     <li>Not this one</li>
     <li>Not this one</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>This one</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried :not() and > and :first-child, but I always get either one element or dozens of them.

It's for a Wordpress generated menu so I don't want to change the id and class names which would probably be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:first` selector

Try,

```
$('ul:first > li')
```

Comment: actually he is right. the fiddle gives all li's the class test

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it.
I also found this: http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/how-to-add-css-classes-to-wordpress-menu-item/#axzz2tGV6AYm4
Although it's kind of a pain because you must declare a class for each item first.

Comment: Doesn't work. 
I went to the fiddle and added a color rule to .test and all of them got affected: 1st and 2nd level.

Comment: @elgati Yes it is obvious, color rule will be applicable for all the descendants unless otherwise you override that.

Comment: Oh, right. 
OK. Let me play around some more with the fiddle. Eventually I want to toggle visibility for descendant ul's but only one at a time.

Comment: Hmm... it's working on the fiddle. I'm alerting the lenght of the selection and it matches, but I can't replicate it on my code. I'll check for duplicate names.
Thanks!

Comment: Got it! I was missing the ">".  (^_^#) Thanks again!